# Stuck UI on accidental dock panel click

Tags: mouse, gnome-shell, xps, ubuntu-dock, context-menu

I am running a vanilla installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS laptop. I do not typically use Ubuntu or this model of laptop, but it seems to be a common configuration.

When I try to switch to another application, I sometimes do *something* to my trackpad which causes a contextual menu to appear and get stuck. Once it appears, I cannot click on anything. Keyboard input still works, and clearly UI elements are receiving mouseover events because their appearance changes.

Then, a few minutes later after a lot of swearing, eventually I can click on things again, but the contextual menus remain open. If I click on them, I get stuck again.

[image]

*Maybe* using the Windows key, which does what I would call Expose or Mission Control on macOS, or hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> gives me mouse control again. I will try them next time. But:

- What am I doing that gets me stuck in this mode?
- How can I regain the ability to click?
- How can I fix the side panel and close these contextual menus when this happens?
- Is there an update that will address this?
- What would be useful to submit in a bug report, if no one else sees this?

Comment: Most probably restarting GNOME shell would fix this (temporarily). To do that, press <Alt><F2>, then type `r`, and finally press <Enter>.